# index file doesn't execute because of .htaccess rewritebase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(index.html|myfolder/anotherfolder)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myfolder/subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myfolder/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

My problem is `domain.com/index.html` works but `domain.com/` displays white empty page.

If I disable RewriteEngine both work but my subfolders stop working.

How can I make index.html and subbfolder work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first ignore rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.html|myfolder/subfolder|)($|/) - [L,NC]
```

Comment: `index\.html` and trailing `|` are correct. [L, `NC`] gives server error. Without `NC` it works.

Comment: That is fine as `NC` is for ignore case comparison only.